# Как отправить с помощью curl запрос на вычисление среднего арифметического и получить в переменную ответ?

Tags: php, curl, url, веб-сайт

Пытаюсь на php/curl написать запрос на получение среднего арифметического в форму на сайте:

http://www.alcula.com/calculators/statistics/mean/#gsc.tab=0

Мне показалось, что он очень простой и вытащить результат получится легко. Однако многочисленные попытки не увенчались успехом:

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.alcula.com/calculators/statistics/mean/#gsc.tab=0');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=5,6,7");
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        echo $out;
        curl_close($curl);
```

попробовал вот так запросить среднее арифметическое чисел 5 6 7, но в ответ приходит страница Bad Request, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно вытянуть среднее арифметическое "курлом" в данном случае? Сколько ни бьюсь, пока ничего не смог придумать!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.alcula.com/calculators/statistics/php_pub/submit_data.php');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
        'func'      => 'submit_data',
        'data_type' => 'Population',
        'data'      => '5,6,7',
    ]);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $out;
    curl_close($curl);
```

П.С
Хотя и проще посчитать самому

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает!